# Reverse the string without changing white spaces in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm working on reversing the string word by word and making sure that all the spaces, tabs and white spaces character etc. are not changed or removed. I have tried few solution using Java, but ending up with no good result. For example , to convert following string

```
 The rule       about++[]      the     input

        stream.
```

And get output like this without removing any white space character.

```
 ehT elur       tuoba++[]      eht     tupni

        maerts.
```

My code

```
String reverseString(String str) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
            temp.append(ch);
        } else {
            result.append(temp.reverse()).append(ch);
            temp.delete(0, temp.length());
        }
    }
    result.append(temp);
    return result.toString();
}
```

I getting same result with one issue that word `about++[]`, should be `][++tuoba0` where as 
it is showing like this  `tuoba++[]`. Any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: According to what you expect, shouldnt the expected output have `about[]++` reversed as `][++tuoba0` instead of `tuoba++[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
```

to

```
if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
```

This way you will include all characters that are not whitespaces. Otherwise you will reverse only alphabetic characters which `[` `]` `+` are not.

Answer (score 2):

`+` and `[]` are not alphabetical, so you are treating them the same way you treat whitespace.    [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) can help you solve your problem.